# Patch and Application Management Software

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, home-server

I recently downloaded a trial of GFI LanGuard for my home network (Server box, 6 PC's, and a couple of laptops, all in a workgroup) to take control of Patch Management and Application updates centrally and automatically. It works pretty well, scheduling audits and such, updating patches and software centrally, service packs etc - but the price is a little steep for a home solution.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any alternatives such like LanGuard that are perhaps Open Source or just cheaper.

Looking for something which can update custom applications - LanGuard was also able to take control of applications like iTunes, WinRAR etc.

Cheers!

Comment: Write your own.

Answer (score 1):

[WSUS?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx)  Works well and support is good.  Have not tried latest but price is right

Comment: Looking for something which can update custom applications - LanGuard was also able to take control of applications like iTunes, WinRAR etc. Thanks for the response though!